# Object and grass dissapear in render

Tags: rendering, hair

I'm suck with this problem. For some reason one of the objects isn't visible in the render (I marked it on the second image). The same thing with the grass, I don't know why but it's not erendering.
Thanks for all advices
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, instead of (not) showing invisible objects in the screenshot it would be better to show some of the settings of these objects. Maybe the marked object in the outliner, is visibility in render disabled maybe? Or the grass (moss?), how is it realized? Is it a particle system? Some kind of render setting? Geometry Nodes? No offense, but to help you we need more information then "it's not there".

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm not proffessional at all( is it okay if I attach my blender file here? Or is it too much?

Comment: No problem. You can upload the blend file here: https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question. Files must be smaller than 30 MB, but to find out what's wrong it might be enough if you stripped down the scene to some crucial parts and save it as a new file to upload. Maybe it's sufficient to keep the object that's missing in render and one object with grass on it.

Comment: so I uploaded a file ( btw I found out the solution with missing object - it was the emitter, another guy from other forum helped me with that, but he didn't know the problem with grass). So i left two stones, tried to render them, and honestly I can see a bit grass on both of them (then previously I only saw it on the right one). So now I guess the question is might be how to make them look more visible? Sorry that I'm that bad...if this question is okay for you, I would be glad to get any adviсes

Comment: This was supposed to be edited into your question... I've done that for you. I'll have a look at the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grass settings are quite low in the example file, especially on the rock to the right. The left one has 1500 particles and 50 children, but the right (larger) rock has only 382 with 40 children.

I would suggest you set at least 1500 for the larger as well, maybe even more. Then in the settings for *Children*, the amount of 40 or 50 is okay for the *Display Amount* (maybe go even lower to have a more responsive viewport while working on the scene), but for *Render Amount* I would go higher.

With a low number of main particles like 1500, I would set the *Render Amount* of *Children* to at least 200. Depending on what your PC is capable of maybe increase the main particle number as well.

For comparison, here are the original settings:

[image: low particles]

And here I increased the particle *Number* on the right rock to 2500, and the *Render Amount* of children to 200 on both rocks:

[image: more particles]

But I guess it's on you to find the best settings for your desired result.

Comment: Oh, thank you so so so much!! Hope didn't get on your nerves too much with these questions, anyway thank you !

Comment: @AnastasiaAmirova Don't worry, everything's fine. If this answer helped you, you might consider accepting it. Read more about it here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)